# efficient convenient sliding/rolling operation on a 2D numpy matrix?

Tags: numpy

I am answering this for anyone who may need it but also if there is a more efficient (but not ugly) way to do this then please answer!

basically I just want to perform a sliding operation on a matrix. so for dataset

`data_in = np.reshape(np.repeat(np.arange(10).T, 4), [10, 4])**2`

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9],
       [16, 16, 16, 16],
       [25, 25, 25, 25],
       [36, 36, 36, 36],
       [49, 49, 49, 49],
       [64, 64, 64, 64],
       [81, 81, 81, 81]])
```

standard deviation for window of 5 (centered) would output

```
nan
nan
5.89915248150105
8.648699324175862
11.436782764396638
14.24078649513432
17.052858997833766
19.86957473123167
nan
nan
```

or with `np.nanstd`

```
1.699673171197595
3.5
5.89915248150105
8.648699324175862
11.436782764396638
14.24078649513432
17.052858997833766
19.86957473123167
16.80029761641144
13.072447700751718
```

Comment: `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` is often used for rolling/sliding window operations, or `as_strided` for a more basic version.

Comment: thanks good to know! I was using pandas dataframe to do sliding window operations for feature engineering but it couldn't operate on a matrix, just an array, ASAIK. Can this operate on a matrix?

Comment: @PhillipMaire. Of course it can. You make it multi-D and choose your axes

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeah I re wrote my code earlier (edit 1) and it it much faster :) thanks

Comment: @PhillipMaire. Faster than the convolution?

Comment: function `data_out_sliding_window_view` in my answer is the fastest that actually gives the output I need and is easily adapted for different operations (can pass in any operation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 1: based on the suggestion from @hpaulj, a found a faster method using `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`

```
def total_rolling_sliding_window_view(data_in, win, operation_function, shift_from_center = 0):
  assert win%2 == 1, 'window must be odd'
  mid = win//2
  pad = np.zeros([win, data_in.shape[1]])*np.nan

  L_pad = pad[:mid-shift_from_center]
  R_pad = pad[:mid+shift_from_center]

  data_in = np.vstack([L_pad, data_in, R_pad])
  w = data_in.shape[1]
  data_in = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(data_in, (win, w))
  data_in = np.reshape(data_in, [-1, win*w])
  data_out = operation_function(data_in, axis = 1)
  return np.asarray(data_out)
  
def total_rolling_operation(data_in, win, operation_function, shift_from_center = 0):
  assert win%2 == 1, 'window must be odd'
  mid = win//2
  pad = np.zeros([win, data_in.shape[1]])*np.nan

  L_pad = pad[:mid-shift_from_center]
  R_pad = pad[:mid+shift_from_center]

  data_in = np.vstack([L_pad, data_in, R_pad])
  
  data_out = []
  for k in range(data_in.shape[0]-win+1):
    x = data_in[k:(k+win)] 
    data_out.append(operation_function(x))
  return np.asarray(data_out)
```

ensure they output the same values

```
data_in = np.reshape(np.arange(10*4), (10, 4))**2
data_out_og = total_rolling_operation(data_in, 5, np.std, shift_from_center = 0)
data_out_sliding_window_view = total_rolling_sliding_window_view(data_in, 5, np.std, shift_from_center = 0)
print(np.asarray([data_out_og, data_out_sliding_window_view]).T)
```

output:

```
[[         nan          nan]
 [         nan          nan]
 [113.49471353 113.49471353]
 [158.48359537 158.48359537]
 [203.98296498 203.98296498]
 [249.71393634 249.71393634]
 [295.56902747 295.56902747]
 [341.49824304 341.49824304]
 [         nan          nan]
 [         nan          nan]]
```

time it

```
w, h = 4, 10000
data_in = np.reshape(np.arange(h*w), (h, w))**2
%timeit -n 10 data_out_og = total_rolling_operation(data_in, 5, np.std, shift_from_center = 0)
%timeit -n 10 data_out_sliding_window_view = total_rolling_sliding_window_view(data_in, 5, np.std, shift_from_center = 0)
```

output:

```
10 loops, best of 5: 256 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 5: 1.6 ms per loop
```

---

Original post:

```
def total_rolling_operation(data_in, win, operation_function, shift_from_center = 0):
  assert win%2 == 1, 'window must be odd'
  mid = win//2
  pad = np.zeros([win, data_in.shape[1]])*np.nan

  L_pad = pad[:mid-shift_from_center]
  R_pad = pad[:mid+shift_from_center]

  data_in = np.vstack([L_pad, data_in, R_pad])
  
  is_nan_inds = []
  data_out = []
  for k in range(data_in.shape[0]-win+1):
    x = data_in[k:(k+win)] 
    data_out.append(operation_function(x))
    is_nan_inds.append(np.any(np.isnan(x)))
  return np.asarray(data_out), np.asarray(is_nan_inds)
```

```
data_in = np.reshape(np.repeat(np.arange(10).T, 4), [10, 4])**2

data_out, is_nan_inds = total_rolling_operation(data_in, 5, np.std, shift_from_center = 0)
_ = [print(i1, i2) for i1, i2 in zip(data_out, is_nan_inds)]
```

output

```
nan True
nan True
5.89915248150105 False
8.648699324175862 False
11.436782764396638 False
14.24078649513432 False
17.052858997833766 False
19.86957473123167 False
nan True
nan True
```

or you could define your own function

```
def custom_nanstd(x):
  return np.sqrt(np.nanmean((x - np.nanmean(x))**2))
data_out, is_nan_inds = total_rolling_operation(data_in, 5, custom_nanstd, shift_from_center = 0)
_ = [print(i1, i2) for i1, i2 in zip(data_out, is_nan_inds)]
```

output

```
1.699673171197595 True
3.5 True
5.89915248150105 False
8.648699324175862 False
11.436782764396638 False
14.24078649513432 False
17.052858997833766 False
19.86957473123167 False
16.80029761641144 True
13.072447700751718 True
```

and if you dont want the requirement for the window to be odd (which ensures data will be centered around a point) you can reconfigure to always start from left or right side.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the variance over `N` samples of `x` as `sum(x**2) - sum(x)**2 / N`, you can use a convolution with a boxcar kernel to do the computation. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve

x = np.array([
    [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
    [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
    [ 4,  4,  4,  4],
    [ 9,  9,  9,  9],
    [16, 16, 16, 16],
    [25, 25, 25, 25],
    [36, 36, 36, 36],
    [49, 49, 49, 49],
    [64, 64, 64, 64],
    [81, 81, 81, 81]])
N = 5
kernel = np.ones((N, 1), 1)
sigma = np.sqrt(convolve(x**2, kernel, mode='valid') - convolve(x, kernel, mode='valid')**2 / N)
```

In this case, we get a `sigma` of

```
array([[13.19090596, 13.19090596, 13.19090596, 13.19090596],
       [19.33907961, 19.33907961, 19.33907961, 19.33907961],
       [25.57342371, 25.57342371, 25.57342371, 25.57342371],
       [31.84336666, 31.84336666, 31.84336666, 31.84336666],
       [38.13135193, 38.13135193, 38.13135193, 38.13135193],
       [44.42971978, 44.42971978, 44.42971978, 44.42971978]])
```

While I'm pretty sure that scipy no longer provides this, the boxcar convolution can be optimized to run in O(n) time.

Comment: can you perform the operation over the matrix such that it outputs a single array? I sure it can be done but not familiar. so operating on `x = np.reshape(np.arange(10*4), (10, 4))**2 ` the output is `[113.49471353 158.48359537 203.98296498 249.71393634 295.56902747
 341.49824304 ]` and then I can time it like I did the other methods, thanks!!